# PHP database display in same fields with different anchor tags

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've searched high and low to see if this is possible and came up empty handed.  Firstly, here's my code:

```
 <div id="information" style="display:none">
 </div>

<?php $seat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE seat='C3-24'"); $row = mysql_fetch_array($seat); ?>

     <ul>
        <li> <?= $row['first_name']; ?></li>
        <li> <?= $row['last_name']?> </li>          
        <li> <?= $row['seat']?></li>            
     </ul>                   

 </div><!-- information -->

 <div id="c3-24" class="seat">
    <a class="trigger" onClick="document.getElementById('information').style.display='block';"></a></div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to update the `li` list when I select a `div id "c3-25"`.  Now I know that having the `WHERE seat="C3-25"` will only output the database row of with that but I want to reuse this structure with other locations.  From what I read this isn't possible.  Ideally I want to have a list of divs (c3-24 to c3-50) and display the corresponding information when the anchor tag is clicked in the `li` fields.

I've tried putting multiple "information" divs but the information just end up stacking on top of one another.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is timing.  There are two very separate execution contexts worth considering to understand your problem:

1. page construction (PHP) - the web server creates HTML to send to the browser;
2. user interaction (JavaScript) - the user's browser has rendered the page and the user is interacting with it.

Since page construction time happens way before the browser gets the information, it can't possibly implement user decisions (which happen later).

The typical solution to this kind of solution is to break up the application into multiple requests.  As a best practice, it's also better to split out your JavaScript into a separate file and use a technique called delegation to reduce the amount of code.

Here's how I'd do it.  First, send down the page structure (PHP/HTML):

```
<div id="information">
  <!-- leave empty -->
</div>
<div class="seats">
  <div class="seat">
    <a class="trigger">c3-24</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="seat">
    <a class="trigger">c3-25</a></div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then set up the user interaction in a separate JavaScript file:

```
// setup a click handler on the parent 'seats' div
document.querySelector('.seats').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  // check if the target of the click was actually an anchor tag with class=target
  if (e.target.classList.contains('target')) {
    var
      // use the text of the anchor tag to get the seat
      seat = e.target.textContent,
      // create an XMLHttpRequest to asynchronously get the seat details
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // handle server result by inserting details
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState === 4){
        document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = req.responseText;
      }
    };
    req.open("GET", "seatdata.php?seat=" + encodeURIComponent(seat), true);
    req.send(null);
  }
});
```

Finally, implement a separate PHP script which gets the data for a specific seat (e.g. seatdata.php).  Your script should get the `seat` URL parameter via `$_GET['seat']` and use that in your query.

Per Madara's comment, don't use the `mysql_query` function directly since it has been deprecated, use something better instead.

Comment: Hey thanks you for your help.  I appreciate the code, you didn't have to do that, I was just looking for a step in the right direction.  I'm just trying now to implement it into my code.  I'll update you with what I come up with.  Thanks again.