# Array in php that can display a row when anchor tag is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I asked this [question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465545/php-database-display-in-same-fields-with-different-anchor-tags) but my friend said to take a different approach.  Instead of constantly pinging the database when a new linked is clicked, he said to narrow down the php array to just the floor in question and convert it to an javascript object so that the data will be there and not have to keep grabbing it from the database.

This is what I'm trying to do - I have a floor map and an anchor tag over the seat and when it is click I want the information from the database to appear in another div above the map.

Now I have a php array with the specific floor but from what I have read that I need to convert it to json.  Now how would I go about selecting the data of the seat that was clicked, grab the data from the json array and display it in the div above the map.  I also want to have the data disappear when a different seat is selected and populate with the new information.

I want to target the the div with the seat#  -> from there grab the information in the javascript -> display in the div above the map.

This is what I have:

```
 <div id="information" style="display:none">
 </div>



 <div id="c324" class="seat seat-department">
<(a) class="trigger" onClick="document.getElementById('info').style.display='block';"></(a)></div>[2]
</div>
```

IF someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: where is the `<div>` with id `seat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally got what I need to work!!!!

this is what I did.

JS

```
var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

function displayInfoForDiv(i){
    document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = jsonData[i].first_name;
    document.getElementById('lname').innerHTML = jsonData[i].last_name;
    document.getElementById('ext').innerHTML = jsonData[i].extension;
    document.getElementById('lvl').innerHTML = jsonData[i].level;
    document.getElementById('seat').innerHTML = jsonData[i].seat;
    document.getElementById('depart').innerHTML = jsonData[i].department;
    document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = jsonData[i].email;

}
```

html

```
      <div id="c234" class="seat">
    <a class="trigger" onClick="displayInfoForDiv(22)"></a>
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps someone and they don't have to spend days trying to get it to work.  Thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to have a script tag that contains the data from your php array somewhere,

```
<script>
    var myInfoStuf = {'c234': 'This is info on the seat'}; // an object of info strings
</script>
```

so, and then in your onclick, which I'd recommend breaking out into a function,

```
function displayInfoForDiv(id) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = myInfoStuf[id];
    document.getElementById('info').style.display='block';
    return false;
}
```

and then you can invoke that onclick handler from you seat like:

```
<div id="c324" class="seat seat-department">
    <class="trigger" onclick="displayInfoForDiv('c234')"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much.  This is exactly the functionality that I wanted.  I am still having a problem connecting my database array and displaying the data but I want to try and play around with it to see if I can get it running.  Thanks for helping me get on the right track and I'll update if I can or can't get the array to display the data.  Thanks again.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for getting it into Javascript